# wordpress - post return localhost "dashboard" after I change domain

Tags: wordpress

I have a blog, i change domain of blog to localhost

[image]

but when i click any post, it return localhost "dashboard"

[image]

What's the problem? 
How to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that REWRITING is ON in your Apache?  Try rebuild htaccess via  wp-admin->settings->permalink->SAVE and then try again

Comment: i did it before post this question

Comment: okay, last question, you wrote "I have a blog, i change domain of blog to localhost"  - how did you do it? where have you provided this change(renaming)? You just changed the name of folder or?

Comment: Error in file .htaccess. i fixed it. Work fine!